# Extending one JavaScript Object Function from Another

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, tinymce

I need to add some functionality to a core JavaScript object function, without touching the original file.

How can I extend the following object function from my object below while keeping the namespace intact?

**core object**

```
    (function() {
        var DOM = tinymce.DOM;

        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.WordPress', {

            // i need to extend this function
            _hideButtons : function() {

                // stuff here

            };

        }); 

        tinymce.PluginManager.add('wordpress', tinymce.plugins.WordPress);

    })();
```

**my object**

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    (function() {

        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Mine', {

            init : function(ed, url) {  

                ed.plugins.wordpress._hideButtons.prototype = function() {

                    // new function stuff

                }
            },  

        }); 

        tinymce.PluginManager.add('mine', tinymce.plugins.Mine);

    })();
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: no takers on this one? i have never extended JS before but this seems like it might be pretty straight forward. i have been checking out some tutorials and docs but this one it throwing me. any help would be great!

Comment: is extend even the right direction. i need to update that function, not clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending was, in fact, **not** what i needed.

by just removing `.prototype` above, allowed me to completely **over write** the function in question. *this is exactly what i wanted to do.*

check it...

```
(function() {

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Mine', {

        init : function(ed, url) {  

            ed.plugins.wordpress._hideButtons = function() {

                // new function stuff

            }
        },  

    }); 

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('mine', tinymce.plugins.Mine);

})();
```